# get mouse position using robotjs is not working in Electron app

Tags: electron

I want to detect desktop idle time from an Electron app. Then i got this link (https://github.com/octalmage/robotjs) from some post. But none of the examples, like getting the position of the mouse etc is not working.

i have installed robotjs using the command

```
    npm install robotjs
```

Then i try the code below in my app.js

```
    var robot = require("robotjs");


    //Get mouse position. 

    var mouse = robot.getMousePos();


    //Get pixel color in hex format. 

    var hex = robot.getPixelColor(mouse.x, mouse.y);

    document.write("#" + hex + " at x:" + mouse.x + " y:" + mouse.y);
```

Anybody have an idea about what's wrong? Any help will be appreciated

Comment: If all you want is to detect when the system is idle then you can use https://github.com/paulcbetts/node-system-idle-time instead.

Comment: Thanks for your reply vadim. how can i install this like robotjs. (Eg: npm install robotjs)?

Comment: When i debug, this is the error iam getting. ELECTRON_ASAR.js:158 Uncaught Error: The system cannot find message text for message number 0x%1 in the message file for %2.
\\?\Directory-Path\node_modules\robotjs\build\Release\robotjs.node

Comment: That error tends to occur when you attempt to load a 64bit module into 32bit Electron (and maybe vice versa). Anyway, make sure you rebuild the `robotjs` module to target the specific version of Electron you're attempting to load it in as documented in http://electron.atom.io/docs/tutorial/using-native-node-modules/

Comment: Great! Thanks Vadim. It seems like you are the only electron expert available here :) . You are the one always answer my doubts here about electron. I dont know how to implement the above documentation, as iam a very beginner in electron.

Comment: Im fed-up with the robotjs, now trying to use npm install system-idle-time.

Comment: Im fed-up with the robotjs, now trying to use npm install system-idle-time. 
But that too returns an error. : 

gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp 
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: 'gyp' failed with exit code:1

can you help me on this

Comment: Can you post a new question with all the relevant errors?